Access Duplicate Table with properties like Lookup Field
Hi I have a table called “RA” and some fields are Lookup Field (hope it's called that in english) so when I click on the cells in this column dropdown opens and I can select multiple things from another table.
I would like to duplicate the table “RA” 1-1 with properties, so if the table RA 2nd column is Lookup Field, the duplicate should also be Lookup Field.
I am quite new to access VBA and I have found a code on the internet. The table is duplicated but the properties Lookup Field etc. are not copied. I would appreciate some help.
here is my code so far, what i found on internet:
Sub DuplicateRATable()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim index As DAO.Index
    Dim rel As DAO.Relation
    Dim newTableName As String

    ' Set the current database
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    
    ' Define the new table name
    newTableName = "RA_Duplicate"
    
    ' Check if the new table already exists and delete if it does
    On Error Resume Next
    db.TableDefs.Delete newTableName
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Copy the original table
    db.Execute "SELECT * INTO " & newTableName & " FROM RA", dbFailOnError
    
    ' Get the original table definition
    Set tdf = db.TableDefs("RA")
    
    ' Loop through the fields of the original table and copy combo box properties
    For Each fld In tdf.Fields
        On Error Resume Next
        ' Check if the field is a combo box
        If fld.Properties("DisplayControl").Value = acComboBox Then
            Dim prop As DAO.Property
            Dim newFld As DAO.Field
            Set newFld = db.TableDefs(newTableName).Fields(fld.Name)
            
            ' Copy combo box properties
            For Each prop In fld.Properties
                On Error Resume Next
                newFld.Properties(prop.Name).Value = prop.Value
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next prop
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next fld
    
    ' Copy indexes
    For Each index In tdf.Indexes
        On Error Resume Next
        ' Create a new index
        Dim newIndex As DAO.Index
        Set newIndex = db.TableDefs(newTableName).CreateIndex(index.Name)
        
        ' Add fields to the new index
        For Each fld In index.Fields
            newIndex.Fields.Append newIndex.CreateField(fld.Name)
        Next fld
        
        ' Copy index properties
        newIndex.Primary = index.Primary
        newIndex.Unique = index.Unique
        newIndex.IgnoreNulls = index.IgnoreNulls
        newIndex.Required = index.Required
        
        ' Append the new index to the new table
        db.TableDefs(newTableName).Indexes.Append newIndex
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next index
    
    ' Copy relationships
    For Each rel In db.Relations
        If rel.Table = tdf.Name Or rel.ForeignTable = tdf.Name Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Dim newRel As DAO.Relation
            Set newRel = db.CreateRelation(rel.Name, newTableName, rel.ForeignTable, rel.Attributes)
            
            For Each fld In rel.Fields
                newRel.Fields.Append newRel.CreateField(fld.Name)
                newRel.Fields(fld.Name).ForeignName = fld.ForeignName
            Next fld
            
            db.Relations.Append newRel
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next rel
    
    MsgBox "The table '" & newTableName & "' has been successfully duplicated."
End Sub



combination fields (hope it's called that in English) : Its Lookup Field

It is much easier using DoCmd.TransferDatabase method (Access) :
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", CurrentDb.Name, actable, "RA", "RA_Duplicate"


thanks for you answer. Could you also help me with full code? couldnt figure it out

@programmervba, Glad to help. Thats All! Just this single line code creates a copy of the RA table (structure/design and data) to a new table RA_Duplicate.

@programmervba, if you want to know why your code does not work as expected, you need to remove (comment) all On Error Resume Next and On Error GoTo 0 and debug the code of the For Each fld In tdf.Fields loop. Properties of the fld  not exist in the newFld  cannot be set before first created. This is atleast one of the reasons why this code does not work. Since error-catching is disable, you cannot see the source of problem.
